# Why do this sample script, keep outputting error near token?

Tags: linux, shell

enter image description hereI was trying to see how a shell scripts work and how to run them, so I toke some sample code from a book I picked up from the library called "Wicked Cool Shell Scripts"

I re wrote the code verbatim, but I'm getting an error from Linux, which I compiled the code on saying:

> 'd.sh: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `{
>
> 'd.sh: line 3:`gmk() {

Before this I had the curly bracket on the newline but I was still getting :

> 'd.sh: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token
>
> 'd.sh: line 3:`gmk()

```
#!/bin/sh
#format directory- outputs a formatted directory listing 
gmk()
 {
#Give input in Kb, output converted to Kb, Mb, or Gb for best output format
    if [$1 -ge 1000000]; then
        echo "$(scriptbc -p 2 $1/1000000)Gb"
    elif [$1 - ge 1000]; then
        echo "$$(scriptbc -p 2 $1/1000)Mb"
    else
        echo "${1}Kb"
        fi
}

    if [$# -gt 1] ; then 
        echo "Usage: $0 [dirname]" >&2; exit 1
    elif [$# -eq 1] ; then 
        cd "$@"
        fi

    for file in *

    do 
        if [-d "$file"] ; then
            size = $(ls "$file"|wc -l|sed 's/[^[:digit:]]//g')
        elif [$size -eq 1] ; then
            echo "$file ($size entry)|"
        else
            echo "$file ($size entries)|"
    fi
        else
            size ="$(ls -sk "$file" | awk '{print $1}')"
            echo "$file ($(gmk $size))|"
    fi
    done | \
      sed 's/ /^^^/g' |\
      xargs -n 2 |\
      sed 's/\^\^\^/ /g' | \
      awk -F\| '{ printf "%39s %-39s\n", $1, $2}'
      exit 0

    if [$#-gt 1]; then 
        echo "Usage :$0 [dirname]" >&2; exit 1
    elif [$# -eq 1]; then 
        cd "$@"
    fi

    for file in *
        do
            if [ -d "$file" ] ; then
                size =$(ls "$file" | wc -l | sed 's/[^[:digit:]]//g')
            if [ $size -eq 1 ] ; then
                echo "$file ($size entry)|"
            else
                echo "$file ($size entries)|"
                fi
            else
                size ="$(ls -sk "$file" | awk '{print $1}')"
                echo "$file ($(convert $size))|"
                fi
done | \
    sed 's/ /^^^/g' | \
    xargs -n 2 | \
    sed 's/\^\^\^/ /g' | \
    awk -F\| '{ printf "%-39s %-39s\n", $1, $2 }'

    exit 0
```

[image: the code as it appears in the book]

Comment: This is badly broken.  To begin with put spaces around `[` and `]`.

Comment: When you say you "compiled" the code, what exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: @devnull I put the spaces like you suggested

Comment: @Gabe Compile is probably not the correct word, just so used to saying it. I tried to run the script using what my other linux book suggest **/bin/sh filename** I aslo tried to run it using **chmod +x filename**  then typing the filename in but kept getting a path error, which the book said may happen, in which they suggested PATH=$PATH then running the filename but it still didn't work

Comment: Did you type in the code to a Linux program?

Comment: parentheses in `gmk()` are wrong. Try to remove them. http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-8.html#ss8.1

Comment: Are you sure you posted the right code? Because I have noticed that `if/else` statements are wrong and there are plenty of duplicated code, such us that used for printing the usage of the program. Please put the right code so we can help you! :D

Comment: @GiuseppePes This the right code, since my level has gone up, I think I'm able to post pictures. I'll post the page from the book

Comment: I copy/pasted the code. No error with `gmk` function, but `bla.sh: 31: bla.sh: Syntax error: "else" unexpected (expecting "done")`

Comment: @GiuseppePes I see what you were referring to, sorry it was a bad copy/paste job when I changed my filename and extension, when I having trouble finding the correct path. It should be correct now

Comment: @Gabe I typed the code in notepad text editor.

Comment: all this script to make `ls -lh`?

Comment: @CarlosCampderrós well yes ls -l, but most of it is just proper formatting of the output. There is a second page that has the last lines of code and the how it works description, but I can only post 1 page at a time

Comment: You used Notepad on Windows to enter the program? How did you get it to your Linux machine?

Comment: @Gabe I'm actually remotely using my school linux sever through xshell. So I just winscp the text file to my school directory and just open it normally.

Comment: This matters because if you create a text file on Windows, you will have `\r\n` line endings. If you do not transfer it to Unix properly, they will not get converted to `\n` line endings, and many Unix programs will fail on them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sh is *very* sensitive to spaces. In particular assignment (no spaces around `=`) and testing (must have spaces inside the `[ ]`).

This version runs, although fails on my machine due to the lack of `scriptbc`.

You put an `elsif` in a spot where it was supposed to be `if`.

Be careful of column alignment between starts and ends. If you mismatch them it will easily lead you astray in thinking about how this works.

Also, adding a `set -x` near the top of a script is a *very* good way of debugging what it is doing - it will cause the interpreter to output each line it is about to run before it does.

```
#!/bin/sh
#format directory- outputs a formatted directory listing
gmk()
{
#Give input in Kb, output converted to Kb, Mb, or Gb for best output format
    if [ $1 -ge 1000000 ]; then
        echo "$(scriptbc -p 2 $1/1000000)Gb"
    elif [ $1 -ge 1000 ]; then
        echo "$(scriptbc -p 2 $1/1000)Mb"
    else
        echo "${1}Kb"
    fi
}

if [ $# -gt 1 ] ; then
    echo "Usage: $0 [dirname]" >&2; exit 1
elif [ $# -eq 1 ] ; then
    cd "$@"
fi

for file in *
do
    if [ -d "$file" ] ; then
        size=$(ls "$file"|wc -l|sed 's/[^[:digit:]]//g')
        if [ $size -eq 1 ] ; then
            echo "$file ($size entry)|"
        else
            echo "$file ($size entries)|"
        fi
    else
        size="$(ls -sk "$file" | awk '{print $1}')"
        echo "$file ($(gmk $size))|"
    fi
done | \
  sed 's/ /^^^/g' |\
  xargs -n 2 |\
  sed 's/\^\^\^/ /g' | \
  awk -F\| '{ printf "%39s %-39s\n", $1, $2}'
  exit 0
```

Comment: Thanks, this actually worked after I was able to do some adjustments to my directory. It did output  some errors about the script bc, but it still outputted correctly

Answer (score 0):

By the way, with respect to the book telling you to modify your PATH variable, that's really a bad idea, depending on what exactly it advised you to do.  Just to be clear, never add your current directory to the PATH variable unless you intend on making that directory a permanent location for all of your scripts etc.  If you are making this a permanent location for your scripts, make sure you add the location to the END of your PATH variable, not the beginning, otherwise you are creating a major security problem.

Linux and Unix do not add your current location, commonly called your PWD, or present working directory, to the path because someone could create a script called 'ls', for example, which could run something malicious instead of the actual 'ls' command.  The proper way to execute something in your PWD, is to prepend it with './' (e.g. ./my_new_script.sh).  This basically indicates that you really do want to run something from your PWD.  Think of it as telling the shell "right here".  The '.' actually represents your current directory, in other words "here".